# Account sign-in details are out of date. Sign in again. (Issue after upgrade to Chrome 33)

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have been trying to follow the sample gdrive in the Google Drive API samples. I started out with Chrome 32 and the login and authorization was working well. I upgraded to Chrome 33 and now the sample fails during authorization and takes me to settings page with this error message - "Account sign-in details are out of date.  Sign in again". I am already signed in to the account, but it still thinks I am not signed in. Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Check chrome.runtime.lastError in the getAuthToken callback. There should be an error string describing what went wrong in a little more detail.

If you're not using the default OAuth client ID and manifest "key" parameter that came with the sample, I would double check that those match up with your registration in the cloud console.